# Why could Ronald Weasley use Charlie's old wand?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

In the first book of Harry Potter it is said that Ron had to use his brother's wand.

- Why and how was that possible?
- Doesn't the "*wand choose the wizard*"?
- Isn't Charlie without a proper wand now?

Here is a quote from [wikipedia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ronald_Weasley%27s_first_wand)-

> The first wand of Ronald Weasley was 12" ash with a core of unicorn
>   hair that stuck out at the end of the wand. It originally belonged to
>   his older brother Charlie.

Comment: If we haven't already passed it, I think we're fast approaching the point where every wandlore question has already been answered.

Comment: I suspect it is as simple as Charlie not originally having  brand new wand in the first place...  Perhaps Charlie's first wand was a second-hand, or low-quality wand (not from Ollivander). Then he upgraded to a proper wand-chooses-wizard wand.  Giving the spare wand to to Ron.  Also, Ron was never really good with his original wand.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - I suspect we are about at that point for just about ANY Potter related question.

Comment: Maybe dupe here? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55046/21267

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120793/why-would-charlie-weasley-give-up-his-old-wand-and-give-it-to-ron

Answer (score 10):

JKR has spoken to this issue on a number of occasions;

The most instructive quote is probably this one regarding [wands and family allegiance](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html):

> **Stephanie:** *If the wand chooses the wizard, then why do wands work when passed down from father to son eg neville had his fathers wand*
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** *As established by Ollivander, **a wizard can use almost any wand, it is simply that a wand that chooses him/her will
>   work best. Where there is a family connection, a wand will work a
>   little better than a wand chosen at random, I think.***

It follows that not only would Ron be able to perform magic with any wand, but that Charlie's old wand would also probably be slightly more effective than another wand.

---

As to what happened to Charlie, the clear implication is that he has a ***new*** wand and that Ron, as the youngest wizard in the family now has to accepted his hand-me-down.

Ollivander repeatedly reminisces over people’s **first** wands, suggesting that replacing them (presumably when they wear out or become broken) is at least a semi-regular occurrence in the lifetime of a wizard.

Comment: I'd imagine it's a bit like a keyboard. When you first get any keyboard, you're clumsy with it, but eventually you learn to touch-type just fine. If you're used to using one for a long time, and someone else hands you their keyboard, you struggle a bit because things don't quite match up with your muscle memory. You can still type on it, but just not with the same accuracy or efficiency.

Comment: But that's like Harry getting a new wand and giving his old one to his son. That's like removing your finger, the wand chooses the wizard didn't the wand already choose Charlie.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock A wizard isn't limited to beeing chosen by a single wand: By the end of the last book, Harry was 'chosen' by three wand: his old wand, the elder wand, and Draco's (former) wand.

Answer (score 4):

Answer of WHY : Because the family was poor

Answer of HOW : Yes, the wand was not having % allegiance to Ron.He **has** to use it.

> Wands will have better response when inherited from the family members

But there is a lot more difference when wand actually chooses a wizard.

Charlie would buy a second wand for him.